# Generating a unique key in SQL Server on a per company basis

Tags: sql-server

I store positions in a SQL Server 2012 database, where each position is defined by a position number and a company number.

The position numbers are unique for each company only.

For instance, my database could have the following

```
POSITION_NO    COMPANY_NO
1                1 
2                1 
3                1 
1                2
2                2
3                2
1                3
```

I need a function which takes a company number as a parameter, and returns the next sequential position number, which in the example table above would be 2 for COMPANY_NO = 3

What I use at the moment is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [DB].[GenerateKey] 
   @p_company_no float(53),
   @return_value_argument float(53)  OUTPUT
AS 
   BEGIN
      DECLARE
         @v_position_no numeric(5, 0)

      SELECT @v_position_no = max(POSITION_NO) + 1
      FROM DB.POSITION_TABLE with (nolock)
      WHERE COMPANY_NO = @p_company_no

      SET @return_value_argument = @v_position_no

      RETURN 

   END
```

I am aware of the potential pitfalls of using with (nolock), but this was added in an unsuccessful attempt to prevent data-locks on my database. In fact, besides the fact that well-written code is obviously preferable, the main reason I am asking this question is to try and cut down the amount of places that could be causing the data-lock.

Is there any way my code could be improved?

Comment: "but this was added in an unsuccessful attempt to prevent data-locks on my database" Well, the deadlocks go away and corruption comes. Deadlocks often happen *because* there would be corruption otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an auxilliary table with sequences, with one row for every company (as you already did):

```
create table seq (company int, sequence int);
go
```

Seed the counters, one for every company (say there are two companies, 1 and 2):

```
insert seq values
(1, 1), (2, 1);
go
```

Then all you need is a way to both update and select the new value in a single statement to avoid race conditions. This is how to do it:

```
declare @next int;
declare @company int;
set @company = 2;
update seq 
set @next = sequence = sequence + 1
where company = @company;
select @next
```

It would be nice to enclose this into a scalar function, but unfortunatelly no updates in functions are allowed. But you already have a stored procedure in place, so just modify the code in it.

And please tell me that the datatypes used are not really floats? Why not ints?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! (the floats are remnants of an automatic conversion from Oracle)

Comment: Is there anything wrong with me NOT seeding the counters, and adding the following code `IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 begin
 insert into seq (company,sequence) values (@company,1) 
 end`

Comment: Probably not, but you might need to make sure it's thread safe. A unique constraint and a bit of error handling will do.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHILE(1=1)
BEGIN
   SELECT @v_position_no = max(POSITION_NO) 
   FROM DB.POSITION_TABLE with (nolock)
   WHERE COMPANY_NO = @p_company_no


   INSERT INTO DB.POSITION_TABLE
   (COMPANY_NO, POSITION_NO)
   SELECT TOP 1 @p_company_no, @v_position_no + 1
   FROM DB.POSITION_TABLE with (nolock)
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM DB.POSITION_TABLE with (nolock)
           WHERE COMPANY_NO = @p_company_no
           AND POSITION_NO = @v_position_no + 1)

    IF(@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
        BREAK;
END

SET @return_value_argument = @v_position_no + 1
```

Note that this would only insert in the second statement if the POSITION_NO + 1 wasn't since added. If it was then it would try again.